# Override part template Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I starting with orchard. I want to override MenuWidgetPart to render as i want. I've created Parts.MenuWidget-MenuWidget.cshtml into Views folder of current theme. But i do not know, how to i can get list menu from Model. Please look my code below:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        @foreach(var m in listMenu){
            <li><a href="#">@m.Text</a></li>
        }
    </ul>
</nav>
```

How to i can get listMenu from Model ?

Answer (score 3):

Templates for `Menu` and `MenuItem` are `Menu.cshtml` and `MenuItem.cshtml`. You can start by copying those files from `/Core/Shapes/Views/` directory to your theme directory. You can modify them as you wish afterwards.

This will, actually modify all your menus on the site. If you want it to be specifically for your widget (`Parts.MenuWidget-MenuWidget.cshtml`) you can start by copying the contents from `Menu.cshtml` to your widget template and continue with modifications from there.

---

EDIT:

To iterate over items you can use the following syntax:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Menu.Items){
    @Display(item)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand whats you said. But i want to know how to i can foreach to menu items list. Example for Menu.cshtml, i have a Model for it, so how to i can access to list menu item ? Thank again!

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the sample of iterating through the menu items..